$f$ holomorphic on $\Omega$ and real-valued on $\Omega\cap \mathbb R$ implies that $f(\overline z)= \overline {f(z)}$?

Conjecture: Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function defined on $\Omega$, an arbitrary connected open subset of $\mathbb C$ containing $z_0$ and $\overline {z_0}$. If $f$ is real-valued on $\Omega\cap \mathbb R$, then $f(\overline {z_0}) = \overline{f(z_0)}$ .

Let $\Omega^*$ denote $\{\overline z\mid z\in \Omega\}$. In the case the region $\Omega$ is symmetric with respect to the real line (or, more generally, $\Omega \cap \Omega^*$ is connected) the conjecture is true. A simple proof consists of noticing that $\overline {f(\overline z)}$ is also holomorphic on $\Omega^*$, that $\overline {f(\overline z)} = f(z)$ on $\Omega \cap \mathbb R$, and an application of the identity principle, concluding that $f(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}$ holds for all $z\in \Omega\cap \Omega^*$.
But if $\Omega \cap \Omega^*$ becomes non-connected (there indeed exists such $\Omega$), the identity principle cannot be applied and the problem becomes subtle; and it does not seem easy to construct an explicit counterexample. So my question is:
In the case $\Omega\cap \Omega^*$ is not connected, is the conjecture true?
(Many questions concerning the identity $f(\overline z) = \overline {f(z)}$ have been asked on this site, but I did not manage to find a duplicate of mine. Please check carefully before marking this as a duplicate)
Edit: The identity principle states that, if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a open and connected set $\mathcal O$ and $f(z)=g(z)$ in some sequence of distinct points with a limit point in $\mathcal O$, then $f=g$ throughout $\mathcal O$.
The identity principle is only valid when $\mathcal O$ is connected, the situation above $\mathcal O$ being $\Omega\cap \Omega^*$. In any non-connected domain, it is not difficult to obtain a counterexample of the identity principle.

I don’t get it. Why can the identity principle not be applied?

@Tedshifrin $f(z)$ is defined on $\Omega$, and $\overline{f(\overline z)}$ is defined on $\Omega^$. Therefore the desired identity $f(z)= \overline {f(\overline z)}$ makes sense only in the domain $\Omega \cap \Omega^$, and we cannot conclude this using the identity principle if $\Omega\cap \Omega^*$ is not connected. The identity principle can be applied only if the domain in question is connected

All you need is for $\Omega\cap\Omega^*$ to be a set with a limit point. Please edit your post to include the precise statement of the identity principle.

@TedShifrin Edited; I hope I am clear enough :)

No, read the statement carefully. You are misinterpreting completely.  $\mathcal O = \Omega\cup\Omega^*$ here.

@geetha290krm It cannot because $\Omega$ contains $z$ and $\overline z$

@TedShifrin But how do you extend definition of $f$ to $\Omega$ to $\Omega\cup \Omega^$* ? f is defined on $\Omega$, and $\overline {f(\overline z)}$ is defined on $\Omega^$, so that $f(z) = \overline {f(\overline z)}$ only makes sense in the domain $\Omega \cap \Omega^$ ! How does this make sense in $\Omega \cup \Omega^*$?

What does "containing $z$ and $\bar z$" mean, when a few words later it is clear that both $f(z)$ and $f(\bar z)$ are defined for all $z\in\Omega$? I suggest you be extremely careful with quantifiers in the entire statement of the conjecture.

@TedShifrin I'm sorry; I meant $z$ and $\overline z$ to be two fixed complex numbers, but later used the phrase "$f(z) = \overline{f(\overline z)}$" to mean a global preperty. My fault. editing

@TedShifrin And, just as a reminder, $\Omega\cap \mathbb R$ is contained in $\Omega \cap \Omega^*$.

You probably want something like $f(z) = \log(z^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Omega = {i, -i} \cup {\arg(z-i) = 0} \cup {\arg(z+i) = \pi}$.

I've already found a counterexample. Turning it into an answer....

@BrianMoehring Truly elegant. My example is not as good as yours. Actually I can't imagine a better one. Be free to write an answer to give the best answer to my question.

The conjecture is false; a counterexample is given by Brian Moehring in his comment. Take
$$
\Omega = \mathbb C \setminus (\{i,-i\}\cup \{\arg(z-i)=0\} \cup \{\arg(z+i)=\pi\})
$$
and $f(z)=\log(z^2+1)$, the branch of $f$ given by $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is holomorphic in connected region $\Omega$ and is real-valued on the real axis. But
$$
f(2i)=f(-2i)=\log 3 - i\pi,
$$
so that $f(\overline{2i})\neq \overline{f(2i)}$.
